# UITableView Bottom Not Reloading

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UIViewController` a `Segmented Controller` a `TableView` and a `TabBar`. The `UIViewController` extends the table view data source and delegate methods and the segmented controller causes different data to be shown on the table view. In segment 0 I only have 1 cell and in segmented 1 I have around 50 cells. The problem is each table view also has a refresh controller for pull down to refresh.

If I'm on segment 1, pull down the table view to have the refresh controller showing, and them quickly tap to the other segment the 4th cell down shows up at the bottom of the table view. Pull down to refresh again doesn't fix this either.
I have `tableView.reloadData()` in my refresh function. As far as I know `reloadData()` only reloads the visible cells, and since that 4th cell down gets hidden as I'm pulling down the refresh controller it doesn't reload it. Any ideas?

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: provide some code and screen shot so we can understand actually what you want .